# Custom color palette Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I created a custom palette following [this tutorial](http://natashatherobot.com/xcode-color-palette/).

How could I use my custom color programmatically?

Comment: You will get a better response if oyu take a crack at it yourself and post the code of your attempt.  If not that, you may want to post additional details

Answer (score 3):

First just copy (add) the swatch file to your project resources.

```
// get plist file URL
if let plistURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("NSColorPanelSwatches", withExtension: "plist") {
    // load plist data
    if let plistData = NSData(contentsOfURL: plistURL) {
        // decode the colors stored at your swatches plist file
        if let colorsArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: plistData).decodeObjectForKey("NSSwatchColorArray") as? [UIColor] {
            for color in colorsArray {
                print(color.description)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to read the `.clr` files rather than the plist at `~/Library/Colors`. If so, use [`NSColorList`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColorList_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000354-DontLinkElementID_4):

```
let colorList = NSColorList(name: "mylist", fromFile: "/path/to/file.clr")!
let color = colorList.colorWithKey("my color name") // return an NSColor
```

`my color name` is the name you give when inside that color well.